# Error: no such column SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Hi guys I am trying to insert a value into my table in sqlite, however I keep getting

`Error: near line 100: no such column: ‘1’`

Table Format:

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
  staff_id  CHAR(5), 
  role      CHAR(1),
  name      CHAR(15), 
  login     CHAR(8), 
  password  CHAR(30), 
  PRIMARY KEY (staff_id)
);
```

Value being inserted:

```
INSERT INTO staff VALUES (‘1’, ‘D’, ‘jake’, ‘jake2’,’jake3’);
```

Comment: is there any row in the table where staff is 1 is exists in table already  ?

Comment: try this one INSERT INTO staff (staff_id,role,name,login,password) VALUES ('1', 'D', 'jake', 'jake2','jake3');

Comment: @JYoThI That starts to work but why is INSERT INTO staff VALUES (‘1’, ‘D’, ‘jake’, ‘jake2’,’jake3’); not working? I was under the impression that it is the correct syntax

Comment: INSERT INTO staff VALUES (‘1’, ‘D’, ‘jake’, ‘jake2’,’jake3’);     notice that jake3 quotes is not proper look closely into that

Comment: the problem is with your quotes ‘

Answer (score 3):

May be problem is with your quotes ‘

But check once by uninstalled app and try to do after that. Because this happens some time due to you changed something like column in you query and application was already run before doing it. Then this newly added coulmn will not available for you for insertion.

Try this once and check is it working or not.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

i think problem is with your quotes. try this one `'` instead of `‘`

```
INSERT INTO staff (staff_id,role,name,login,password) VALUES ('1', 'D', 'jake', 'jake2','jake3');
```

Comment: I had this issue as well because I was typing the query in Word and copying to the console